# How to authenticate qliksense enterprise and connect from the browser

Tags: qliksense

I'm building a qliksense mashup using React. I can authenticate and connect to the SaaS version of qliksense and would now like to connect to the Enterprise version of qliksense. How can I authenticate and connect from the browser. Would that be possible and how?

Comment: https://medium.com/data-lit/qlik-sense-mashups-in-react-8baee3e94f76

Answer (score 0):

It seems like this doc may help you:
https://help.qlik.com/en-US/sense/June2020/Subsystems/Hub/Content/Sense_Hub/UserInterface/start-dt.htm#anchor-1

It sounds like you need to use Qlik Sense Desktop.

Here is another link that might help:
https://help.qlik.com/en-US/sense-developer/May2021/Subsystems/Mashups/Content/Sense_Mashups/Howtos/mashups-deploy-mashup-intro.htm

This link specifically goes over the workflow for Authentication and Mashups:
https://help.qlik.com/en-US/sense-developer/May2021/Subsystems/Mashups/Content/Sense_Mashups/mashups-introduction.htm

And this one for specific Authentication Details:
https://help.qlik.com/en-US/sense-admin/May2021/Subsystems/DeployAdministerQSE/Content/Sense_DeployAdminister/QSEoW/Deploy_QSEoW/Server-Security-Authentication-Solutions.htm

Javascript requires SAML for SignleSignon.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this via redirect, here is an example in Angular (https://github.com/qlik-oss/enigma.js/blob/master/examples/complete/car-models/README.md). The authentication flow would be the same in React.

The framework I've built, Motor.js also supports this out of the box (https://motor.so/).

Thanks,
Luke